# Tip for calculating an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to calculate this integral and have no idea what technique to use. Can anyone give me a hint?

$$
\int_{a}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{r}\bigg(3\dfrac{\cos(kr)}{(kr)^2}-3\dfrac{\sin(kr)}{(kr)^3}+\dfrac{\sin(kr)}{kr}\bigg) dr, \ \mbox{where} \ a,k > 0 \ \mbox{are constant}
$$

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to compute the antiderivative "manually", step by step:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Then we just need to calculate the improper integral as x approaches$+\infty$.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

$$\int\limits_{r=a}^\infty \frac{\sin (r)}{r^n}\ dr = \frac{a^{2-n} \,
   _1F_2\left(1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2},2-\frac{n}{2};-\frac{a^2}{4}\right)}{n-2}+\cos
   \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-n)$$

where $F$ is a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a reference where I can get more details of the hypergeometric function?

Comment: Ummm... you didn't even try a web search?!?!?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function